# copying excel cells one by one and not range at once

Tags: excel, copy, cells

I'm developing some excel macros, and now I'm stucked with following, 
I want the macro getting the cells from another file and put it on the new one but it is important to consider that copy the full range is not an option, so for example first i Need to copy a1 then a2 , etc ...
the reason is because after each "paste" process, I have to check, the old value and then start a triger of another macro depending on both values, and if ai paste the full range at once it is not working,.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `Cells` value at given row and column from the `Worksheet` objects you are manipulating.

Example : I want to copye the value (cell content only, not style) from worksheet1 cell A1 to worksheet2 cell B3.

```
worksheet2.Cells(3, 2).Value = worksheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Simple as that.